# Should I use a foreach for this PHP script to work as expected?

Tags: php, file-io, while-loop

I have a script that searches through a directory for files containing a particular string (e.g 5126). It then renames each file that does have that string in its filename and prefixes the filename with another string (e.g. 'coursefile5126). This bit works fine. After the string has been renamed, I want an email to be sent to the person whose file this is. At the moment, my script only emails the last person returned in the array, with the links to all files. Please see examples and code below.

example filename:

- Test_47-20120908-154525-5126.zip
- Test_48-20120908-155253-5126.zip
- Test_49-20120908-160226-5125.zip

example array:

- email1@email.com, 51, 26
- email2@email.com, 51, 25

As you see, test_47 and test_48 links should be sent to email1@email.com and test_49 should be sent to email2@email.com, but at the moment, all emails are sent to the last email in the array (email2@email.com in this example)

Can anyone please give me a clue as to where I am going wrong with this?

Thanks.

```
 $dh  = scandir("courses/");
        ...some SQL query here that returns an array
  $i=0;
  while ($data= mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $j=1;
  //this is the array returned by the SQL query
  echo $data["email"]."-".$data["id_cart"]."-".$data["id_product"]."<br/>";
  while ($j<sizeof($dh)) {  //Ensures there are courses to look for

  // this looks for courses that have not yet been renamed and prefixes them with the string  'coursefile' if necessary

  if(end(explode("-",$dh[$j]))==$data["id_product"].$data["id_cart"].".zip" &&   reset(explode("-",$dh[$j])) != 'coursefile')
      {
       rename('courses/'.$dh[$j],'courses/'.'coursefile-'.$dh[$j]);                         

       //sends email   ---- this is where my problem lies I think
       $to      = $data["email"];
       $subject = 'Your link to download your course';
       $message = 'Link: http://www.website.com/courses/'.'coursefile-'.$dh[$j];
       $headers = 'From: contact@website.com' . "\r\n" .
       'Reply-To: contact@website.com' . "\r\n";

       mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
       }
       $j++;
       }             
      }
```

Comment: Sorry, but your code is basically incomprehensible.

Comment: unfortunately I inherited this code, I thought I would be the only one finding it difficult to understand, clearly I am not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit difficult to understand, but from your description here is my suggestion:

You can use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to simplify your search and remove all the unnecessary conditionals. So the code could become:

```
// This needs to be adjusted to the current settings.
$full_path = $current_path . '/courses';

...some SQL query here that returns an array
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{
    // this is the array returned by the SQL query
    echo $data["email"]."-".$data["id_cart"]."-".$data["id_product"]."<br/>";

    // This is what we are looking for for every user
    $key = $data["id_cart"] . $data["id_product"];

    foreach (glob("{$full_path}/*-{$key}.zip") as $filename) 
    {
        // glob returns the full path so we need to split it from
        // the actual filename. I am assuming that the $full_path 
        // is known and it is the full path for the courses/ folder.
        // $real_filename contains the name of the file processed 
        // (used in checking if the file has been renamed and in renaming)
        $real_filename = str_replace($full_path, '', $filename);

        // Check if the file has already been processed i.e. renamed
        if (substr($real_filename, 0, 11) != 'coursefile-')
        {
            // There are files so, rename and then email
            rename($filename, $full_path . 'coursefile-' . $real_filename);                         

            // sends email
            $to      = $data["email"];
            $subject = 'Your link to download your course';
            $message = 'Link: http://www.website.com/courses/'
                     . 'coursefile-' . $real_filename;
            $headers = 'From: contact@website.com' . "\r\n" 
                     . 'Reply-To: contact@website.com' . "\r\n";

            $mail_status = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        }
    }
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you Nikolaos, it works a treat. I had to change the glob() pattern as it wouldn't take the curly braces (even with the flag). Thanks for taking the time to come up with this much better code.